# hot to read out part of website with Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to read out PREVIOUS ROLLS from https://csgoempire.com/ but I always get an empty array.
How can I read out? any suggestions?

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self, 100)
out = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".h-24")))
last_rolls = self.find_elements_by_class_name("h-24")
```

Comment: This is a class tag having no text ,image, link inside it .What exactly you want to read out from these previous roles?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```py
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
try:
    driver.get("https://csgoempire.com")
    time.sleep(2) # Wait for page to load, increase if not enough
    s = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

    for i, coin in enumerate(s.find_all("div", {"class": "previous-rolls-item"})):
        if coin.find("div", {"class": "coin-t"}) is None:
            print(i+1, "CT coin")
        else:
            print(i+1, "T coin")

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Output would be:

```
1 T coin
2 T coin
3 CT coin
4 CT coin
5 T coin
...
```

Make sure to tell me if it worked.

Comment: Thank you I will try but before I have to check BeautifulSoup. I never used that before. But a big thanks for the help.